# add the icon tag to the innerHTML in a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a function in JavaScript, which on the button click changes class and adds a green checkmark, which is the icon tag in html.

I tried this:

```
function markerValg(btnID) {
    knap = document.getElementById(btnID);
    knap.classList.remove("unselected");
    knap.classList.add("selected");
    document.getElementById(btnID).innerHTML = += <i class="fa fa-check ikon"></i>
```

Comment: If you're receiving an error (which I assume you are), it's probably the `.innerHTML = +=`, which should be one or the other.

Comment: try `document.getElementById(btnID).innerHTML = document.getElementById(btnID).innerHTML+ '<i class="fa fa-check ikon"></i>';`

Comment: I assume you've got a syntax error? You didn't actually tell us what goes wrong. Did you check your Console? Your HTML snippet needs to be in a quoted string, and also you can't write `= +=` all at once - makes no sense. Choose one or other, depending on your requirement. Instead: `document.getElementById(btnID).innerHTML += "<i class="fa fa-check ikon"></i>";` might be more accurate.

Comment: If "_add_" should be taken literally, then you do `document.getElementById(btnID).insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', '<i class="fa fa-check ikon"></i>');`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line of code to

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-check ikon"></i>';
```

```html
<button id='test'>Check</button>
```